# Inserting data into a table with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, database

I am using arrays to insert data into a table named tPerson. If the script succeeded in its role, it would echo:

> SQL:
>   INSERT INTO tPerson ( Salutation, FirstName, LastName, CompanyID )VALUES ( Mr, Morris, Sparrow, 4 )( Mrs, Mary, Haslett, 2 )( Ms, Gill, Hennesey, 1 )
>
> was SUCCESSFUL.

It doesn't succeed in its job and echoes out:

> SQL:
>   INSERT INTO tPerson ( Salutation, FirstName, LastName, CompanyID )VALUES ( Mr, Morris, Sparrow, 4 )( Mrs, Mary, Haslett, 2 )( Ms, Gill, Hennesey, 1 )
>
> FAILED.

My code is as follows:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$databaseName = "alphacrm";

$dbConnected = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
$dbSelected = @mysql_select_db($databaseName, $dbConnected);

$dbSuccess = true;
if ($dbConnected) {
    if (!$dbSelected) {
        echo "DB connection FAILED<br><br>";
        $dbSuccess = false;
    } else {
        echo "DB connection SUCCESSFUL<br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "MySql connection FAILED<br><br>";
}
}

// Execute code ONLY if connections were successful

if ($dbSuccess) {

{ // setup ARRAY of field names

    $personField = array(
        "Salutation" => "Salutation",
        "FirstName" => "FirstName",
        "LastName" => "LastName",
        "CompanyID" => "CompanyID"
    );
}

{ // setup ARRAY of data ROWS

    $personData[0] = array("Mr","Morris","Sparrow","4");
    $personData[1] = array("Mrs","Mary","Haslett","2");
    $personData[2] = array("Ms","Gill","Hennesey","1");

    $numRows = sizeof($personData);
}

{ // SQL statement with ARRAYS

    //Fieldnames part of INSERT statement

    $person_SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO tPerson (
        ".$personField["Salutation"].",
        ".$personField["FirstName"].",
        ".$personField["LastName"].",
        ".$personField["CompanyID"]."
        )";

// VALUES part of INSERT statement

$person_SQLinsert .= "VALUES ";

$indx = 0;
$person_SQLinsert .= "(
    ".$personData[$indx][0].",
    ".$personData[$indx][1].",
    ".$personData[$indx][2].",
    ".$personData[$indx][3]."
    )";

$indx++;
$person_SQLinsert .= "(
    ".$personData[$indx][0].",
    ".$personData[$indx][1].",
    ".$personData[$indx][2].",
    ".$personData[$indx][3]."
    )";

$indx++;
$person_SQLinsert .= "(
    ".$personData[$indx][0].",
    ".$personData[$indx][1].",
    ".$personData[$indx][2].",
    ".$personData[$indx][3]."
    )";

}

{ // Echo and execute the SQL and test for success

    echo "<strong><u>SQL:<br></u></strong>";
    echo $person_SQLinsert."<br><br>";

    if (mysql_query($person_SQLinsert)) {
        echo "was SUCCESSFUL.<br<br>";
    } else {
        echo "FAILED.<br><br>";
    }
}
} // END ($dbSuccess)

?>
```

All help at all will be appreciated as I am quite stumped as to why my script is not working.

Comment: u need to set the values within single quote and it will solve the issue.

Comment: You also need to put a comma between the `VALUES` sets (i.e. `(...), (...), (...)`).

Comment: Please don't use mysql_*, use mysqli_* (improved) instead.

Comment: How would using mysqli benefit?

Comment: What was the sql error? try http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and be prepared to post your table structure as displayed by SHOW CREATE TABLE tPerson

Comment: I don't actually see where I could put an error detector

Answer (score 0):

Just like that @mysql_select_db used for @mysql_query instead of this mysql_query.
Also checked your mysql connection and database connection successful.

Your query for multiple row must be in this format
"INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 );"

Print your query and check it with this syntax.

Comment: The database and mysql connections are successful.

Comment: Yea, it is still returning the FAILED message

Comment: Your query for multiple row must be in this format "INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 );"

Print your query and check it with this syntax.

Comment: I have changed my code and the output is this:
INSERT INTO tPerson ( Salutation, FirstName, LastName, CompanyID ) VALUES( Mr, Morris, Sparrow, 4 ), ( Mrs, Mary, Haslett, 2 ), ( Ms, Gill, Hennesey, 1 );
It still gives the output "FAILED".